# adrotator control is not showing images

Tags: asp.net

I am using adrotator control to display images.But it is not showing images.It is displaying alternate text only.My code is:

```
<Advertisements>
  <Ad>
      <Imageurl>~/adsimages/deal1.jpg</Imageurl>
    <Navigateurl>http://localhost:56788/adsimages/deal1.jpg</Navigateurl>
    <AlternateText>NEW DEALS</AlternateText>
    <Impressions>5</Impressions>
  </Ad>
<Ad>
      <Imageurl>~/adsimages/images(1).jpg</Imageurl>
    <Navigateurl>http://localhost:56788/adsimages/images (1).jpg</Navigateurl>
    <AlternateText>CHECK OUT NEW DEALS</AlternateText>
    <Impressions>3</Impressions>
  </Ad>
</Advertisements>


<asp:AdRotator ID="AdRotator1" runat="server" AdvertisementFile="~/ads.xml" Target="_blank"/>
```

Comment: it would be usefull to have a look at your browser's developer tools `NETWORK` tab, but most probably the problem is the path to your images... you will see that as the requests to your images probably are receiving 404 response status

Comment: `~` at the start of a url tends to mean "user's home directory". e.g. `~foo/bar.html` looks in user foo's home directory. `~/` is "home directory of current user", which is going to be the user that your webserver run under.

Comment: I have folder adsimages in my webapp and i have saved my above images in that folder.and so i have given above path.I could not find out what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

XML files are case sensitives..
Try :

```
<Advertisements>
    <Ad>
        <ImageUrl>~/adsimages/deal1.jpg</ImageUrl>
        <NavigateUrl>http://localhost:56788/adsimages/deal1.jpg</NavigateUrl>
        <AlternateText>NEW DEALS</AlternateText>
        <Impressions>5</Impressions>
    </Ad>
</Advertisements>
```